# How to change currency symbol in filter Magento 2

Tags: magento2, filter, currency

I am new in Magento 2 and in frontend category page there is a filter by price which is range and under it there are two inputs which are `disabled` and there values are `from - to` price and the currency symbol is not right as it shows `$` and the currency I use is `egp`. How can I change it or even remove it?. Just need to know what is the file that I need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration in the backend.

Path: `Stores >> Currency >> Currency Symbol`

Change default symbol **$** to **E£**.

Flush cache `php bin/magento cache:flush` and check it.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: It didn't work. the store currency is just fine and it shows in the right way in products price, except that place. I need the file that shows these two inputs.

Comment: It means you want to change symbol only in filter?

Comment: YES, in filter disabled inputs.